# The Popen function not working on Microsoft IIS 10

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

StackOverFlow.

I am using CodeIgniter 3, in IIS 10, on my site I use the popen () function, but it does not execute the file ..

Code:: `popen("C:/inetpub/wwwroot/CIProject/emulators/0/open.bat", "r");`

Informations:

 - PHP Version: **7.3.6**
 
 - CI Version: **3**

Any possible solution to my problem?

Comment: Check [`pclose()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pclose.php) for errors.

Comment: The [pclose()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pclose.php) function did not return anything.

Comment: It should return an integer. The docs also say that `If PHP has been compiled with --enable-sigchild, the return value of this function is undefined.` so you should verify whether this is affecting you.

Comment: The PHP not has been compiled with `--enable-sigchild`.